# Is std::find suitable only for containers whose elements may be not sorted?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, stl, tradeoff

We can use `std::find` on `std::set`, but it may be slow because `std::set` has a member function `std::set::find` that is often faster than `std::find`.

Is `std::find` suitable only for containers whose elements may be not sorted, e.g. `std::list`?

Can `std::find` prevent the user from using it to find something on `std::set`?

Comment: The *requirements* are here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find, although it isn't entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: What about `unoredered_set` and `unordered_map`?

Comment: std::find is not suitable for containers at all, it receives a pair of iterators. These iterators only have to satisfy InputIterator requirements. There is nothing that requires random access or takes advantage of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you can use *std::find* with all the containers which provide you with *input iterators*. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is the info about *std::find* with its iterator requirements.

The main question is effectiveness. The algorithm does not know anything about the inner representation of the container it works with. So *std::find* simply iterates over the elements of the particular container.There is no way to prevent it from dealing with containers like *std::set*. Moreover, it will be contradictory to the design of *STL*.

As a general rule you should prefer container methods to the algorithms with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the container, std::find() will always take **O(n)** for the worst case, since underneath it simply does linear iterative search, and compares the values pointed by the iterator.

So it is not capable of taking the benefit of whether elements in that container are sorted, or not.

And no,  `std::find` does not prevent the user to find something on `std::set`.